# How to build a search form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, textinput

I'm trying to make a simple search form for my app. All I want to do is search through the `internship` column of my `user` table. I've tried a few different ways but nothing works for me. I don't really want to use plugins like Solr or Elasticsearch either; I just want to stay within the Rails framework. Does anyone have a working example of code they could post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is mine...

In my Model:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      losearch = search.downcase
      where('lower(artist) LIKE ?, "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%")
    end
  end
```

In my Controller:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @pins = Pin.search(params[:search])
  else  
    @pins = Pin.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50).order("created_at DESC")
  end  


  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @pins }
    # format.js
  end
end
```

In my view:

```
<div class="index_search">
  <%= form_tag(pins_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>
  <div class="input-append">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "span2  form-control", placeholder: "Search Reviews" %>
    <!-- In order to have the "search" icon int the button, we need to use plain HTML instead 
         of using a Rails form helper -->
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    <% end %>
  </div> 
</div>
```

You'll want to change the "pins_path" above to whichever path you need and the 'lower(artist) LIKE ?' should be 'lower(internship)'

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do something with the controller?

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I changed it above. The .paginate part is only in my controller because I use pagination. You could leave that out if you don't use it.